# Flash Loader works only inside of Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, loader

I need to load flex swf file into a flash (a button on witch I need to apply flex skin). I'm using flash Loader() and inside of Flash it works fine (swf is loaded and displayed). But when I try run a compiled flash swf, the Loader does not load the flex swf. There are no errors handled with IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR and the ProgressEvent.PROGRESS just sais that 0 bytes was loaded. Than nothing else happen.

Here is a part of my code (just display flex button and set a label):

```
var flexBtn:String = "button.swf"; //swf file is in the same folder as flash source code
var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();
myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,loadComplete);
myLoader.load(new URLRequest(flexBtn));
stage.addChild(myLoader);

var timer:Timer;

function loadComplete(event:Event):void
{
    timer = new Timer(200);
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timeHandler);
    timer.start();
}

function timeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    timer.stop();
    var myClip:MovieClip = myLoader.content as MovieClip;
    myClip.x = 10;
    myClip.y = 10;
    if (myClip.currentFrame == 2){
        myClip.application.flexButton.label = "FlexButton";
    }
}
```

I have tried different versions of SDK and different Loaders but it didn't work.

All suggestion will be appreciated :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `SecurityErrorEvent` - I guess it's because of a privacy policy error.
And of course you must be sure they are in the exact same folder (correct url).

Comment: It seems that it was really a security problem. Now it's working :-)